# Java Swing - JDialog default focus

Tags: java, swing, focus, jdialog

I have found [in the Internet](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/dialog-focus/) such an info:

"When a JDialog (or JFrame for that matter) is made visible, focus is placed on the first focusable component by default."

Let's consider such a code:

```
public class MyDialog extends JDialog{
    // Dialog's components:
    private JLabel dialogLabel1 = new JLabel("Hello");
    private JLabel dialogLabel2 = new JLabel("Message");
    private JButton dialogBtn = new JButton("Sample Btn text");

    public MyDialog(JFrame parent, String title, ModalityType modality){
        super(parent, title, modality);
        dialogBtn.setName("Button");    //
        dialogLabel1.setName("Label1"); // - setting names
        dialogLabel2.setName("Label2"); //
        setTitle(title);
        setModalityType(modality);
        setSize(300, 100);
        setLocation(200, 200);
        // adding comps to contentPane
        getContentPane().add(dialogLabel1, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        getContentPane().add(dialogBtn, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        getContentPane().add(dialogLabel2, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        pack();
    }

    public void showDialog(){
        setVisible(true);
        listComps(rootPane.getComponents());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    /*
     * Itereates through all subcomps recursively and displays some relevant info
     * OUTPUT FORM:  ComponentName | isFocusable | hasFocus
     */
    private void listComps(Component[] comps){
        if(comps.length == 0) return;  
        for(Component c : comps){       
            JComponent jC = (JComponent)c;
            System.out.println(jC.getName() + " | " + jC.isFocusable() +" | " + jC.hasFocus());
            listComps(jC.getComponents());
        }    
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 400));
        frame.setVisible(true);
        JButton btn = new JButton("Show dialog");
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog(frame, "Sample title", ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                    dialog.showDialog();
            }
        });
        frame.add(btn, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
    }
}
```

Output is:
run:

```
null.glassPane | true | false
null.layeredPane | true | false
null.contentPane | true | false
Label1 | true | false
Button | true | true
Label2 | true | false
```

Why focus is set to the JButton?? It is not the first focusable component! 
When I've removed JButton, focus wasn't gained to any component. Why? All compos are focusable by default...

Comment: What would it mean to give focus to a label? It seems like the button is the only component for which focusing makes sense.

Comment: good question, creating a new Top-Level Container (based on pers from Native OS) is quite hard and long action, 1. required wrap into invokeLater == Oracle tutorial Concurency in Swing - Initial Tread, 2. or pack and setVisible(true), 3. use code tags

Comment: Simply write `dialogLabel1.requestFocusInWindow();` at the end of `MyDialog()` constructor, then `JLabel` will take the focus instead of `JButton` ...

Comment: @Heuster I'm asking because when I register some keyStrokeEvents in rootPane's inputMap with WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT I have a problem when my dialog has only JLabels inside. KeyStroke will not be precessed in that case, while it has no comp with focus. It that case a have to artificially set label.setFocusable(true). But probably it is the only way

Comment: @nIcEcOw Thanks, that's exacly what I'm doing now, but I thought there is maybe some other solution ;)

Comment: @guitar_freak : Actually `JLabel` is basically used for displaying `Text or Images`. It is really not used to perform some sort of an action, as already commented by __Heuster__. It is still hard to say, why exactly you need `JLabel` to acquire focus ,  in the absence of the knowledge of what exactly is the requirement. Might be there is an approach, which you not thinking about :-) For the rest you're MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILING :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> It is not the first focusable component! When I've removed JButton, focus wasn't gained to any component. Why? All compos are focusable by default.

To answer the why: it's the decision of the FocusTraversalPolicy, particularly the accept(..) in DefaultFocusTraversalPolicy which ultimately falls back to the dummy NullComponentPeer (which is not focusable by default, as it doesn't really exist :-)

From your comment, it looks like the real question might be "how to implement keyBindings if the rootPane has no focusable children" - if so, the options are

- use the rootPane's componentInputMap, that is WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW
- force the rootPane itself into focusable (probably best doing this only if there are no focusable children)

Comment: I never seen JDialog (decorated or not) with parent (modal/modality or on) that lost focus, even there are only JLabels, please or miss I something

Comment: @mKorbel ?? - sorry, don't understand what you mean

Comment: if I understant OP has issue with  JDialogs focus, then s/he tried whatever ZOO with its childs (there are a few questions with a new unix or linux core on Java7(Open JDK)) or I missread and don't undertand ???

Comment: @mKorbel without any _really_ focusable children, the dialog is the focusOwner which is a problem because the dialog is not a child of the rootPane so that when-ancestor-of-focused-component bindings will not be activated (that's how I understand the OP, could be wrong of course :)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [JLabel javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html) It says:

> A display area for a short text string or an image, or both. A label does not react to input events. As a result, it cannot get the keyboard focus

I think this is the reason why your label does not get the focus.

Comment: The oddity is the return value of `isFocusable()`